# Is possible to print a string of non printable characaters in C

Tags: c

I have a firmware for a low resources microcontroller; currently I have defined a default preset as string

```
#define defaultTypes "211110000" //From ASCII 0 to ASCII 9
```

Then in the main code I print this in a buffer in RAM with sprintf() and use a for loop to read each byte since each byte belong to a variable that the user can set to fulfill his needs.

Now I need to change this to use non printable characters from 0x00 to 0xFF
So I need to create a define like

```
#define defaultTypes 0x02,0x01,0x01,0x01....
```

and load this in to RAM buffer with sprintf()
Or maybe you have a better approach.

Comment: I find the concept of printing non-printable characters amusing.

Comment: If one of the bytes in the "string" of nonprintable characters might be `0x00`, you're not going to be able to treat it as a string, with `sprintf` or otherwise.

Comment: @SteveSummit Yes, that's was I thinking, that's why I ask for a better approach.

Comment: When you "print this in a buffer in RAM", is that something that you could instead just use an initializer for?  For example, is the buffer declared as a (non-VLA) array of `char`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger If I do unsigned **int8 rambuffer[13]={0x02,0x01,0x01};** it compiles but if I try to load that value later in the code I get an error "A numeric expression must appear here". And I need to load the buffer with data from an external EEPROM first; and if I get invalid values from EEPROM then I must to set the default values from code. This way I avoid to get corrupt configuration.

Comment: @E_Blue, that error sounds like a problem with the code in which you are trying to access this `rambuffer`, not with where it is located.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Seems like the compiler support assignation in the declaration unsigned int8 rambuffer[13]={0x02,0x01,0x01}; but not more deep in the code rambuffer[13]={0x02,0x01,0x01};

Comment: @E_Blue, initialization in the declaration is not assignment.  And no, you cannot assign to a whole array.  That was never my suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

`sprintf()` is a slightly strange choice, as you have no formatted substitutions to do.  Instead, you could copy directly the buffer in RAM using [`memcpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy).  It could look like this:

```
uint8_t  data[] = { defaultTypes } ;  // your 0x01 etc.
memcpy(buffer, data, sizeof data);
```

Comment: Is not C for an x86 or an ARM, is for PIC microcontroller. The "string" is in the code itself and to use those values I need to load that in to the RAM. If I do **unsigned int8 rambuffer[13]={0x02,0x01,0x01};** it compiles but if I try to load that value later in the code I get an error "A numeric expression must appear here".

Comment: If you want to change the value of `data[]` after its initial definition, then you still have choices - you can assign individual elements with `data[i] = new_byte_value;` or copy data from somewhere else in over some elements with `memcpy(data + i, pointer_to_first_byte_to_copy, num_bytes_to_copy);`.  If you don't show us exactly what you're trying to do, it's hard to give more specific advice.

Comment: I need to load the buffer with data from an external EEPROM first; then, if I get invalid values from EEPROM, I must to set the default values from code to the external EEPROM. This way I avoid to get corrupt configuration. Anyway, I just solved creating two buffers, one empty and one with the default data and if the buffer that get data from the external EEPROM is corrupt I send the data in the default buffer to EEPROM; this way I avoid to copy data with sprintf or memcpy.